# When I recalculate Bone Roll in Edit Mode the recalculation doesn't transfer over to pose mode

Tags: modeling, animation

The bones in my characters right leg are misaligned in pose mode, but look just fine in Edit mode. Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

This makes it impossible to animate my character, as when I can't really move that leg forward without it skewing to the right...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Its because you use IKs. They are only calculated in Pose Mode. If you are using IKs its really important that your Bones that are affected are not in a straight line, else the algorithm will not know in which direction to bend. Also in the IK settings there is a Pole Angle with which you can experiment after you created that bend. To create that bend I recommend to move the knee connection almost to the skin, that will help later with deformation